# Explain how my Computer Reads my Towers of Hanoi Code

Tags: java, recursion

So I found this Towers of Hanoi code online in an attempt to teach myself recursion:

```
public class TowerOfHanoi {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many disks are there?");
int disks = input.nextInt();

Towers(disks, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}

public static void Towers(int n, char from, char inter, char to) {
if(n == 1) {
  System.out.println("Disk 1 from " + from + " to " + to);
} else {
  Towers(n - 1, from, to, inter);
  System.out.println("Disk " + n + " from " + from + " to " + to);
  Towers(n - 1, inter, from, to);
  }
 }
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to correlate this code to the output. For example, the first line that is outputted says, "Disk 1 from A to C". I know that this is from the first if statement, but I don't know why that line is executed before the rest. Also, what happens after the first `Towers(n-1, from, to, inter)`? I believe this calls the method again, but when are the lines after that executed?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn to use a debugger, so you can step through the code and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to teach yourself recursion it may be more useful to use a simpler example. Consider a recursive approach to solving for a factorial, i.e. 5!. The equation to solve any factorial is n! = n * (n - 1)!. So the math for 5! is just 5x4x3x2x1. An example in Java for this would be as follows:

```
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = factorial(5);
        System.out.println("Final result: " + result);
    }

    public static int factorial(int i) {
        if(i == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int j = i * factorial(i - 1);
            System.out.println(j);
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

This program would output the following:

```
1
2
6
24 
120
Final result: 120
```

As far as understanding the output, it's helpful to think about what the program is doing. Initially, we call the function factorial with an input of 5. The first thing that is hit is the if statement. 5 > 0, so we continue to the else block. There, the first operation is "int j = i * factorial(i - 1)". Here we see the function called again. You can think of this as a "pause" where we wait for that new function call to complete before continuing. So our initial call is now stopped there.

- Initial call paused, waiting on the function call of factorial(5-1) to complete.

We've now called factorial with an input 4. The logic will flow the same way, hit the else block, and then get paused again on the line "int j = i * factorial(i - 1). So now we have:

- Initial call paused, waiting on the funciton call of factorial(5-1) to complete
- Second call paused, waiting on the function call of factorial(4-1) to complete.

Starting to see where this is going? Eventually, we will continue along this way, until i gets all the way down to 0. When that happens, we'll have the following states:

- Initial call paused, waiting on the funciton call of factorial(5-1) to complete
- Second call paused, waiting on the function call of factorial(4-1) to complete.
- Third call paused, waiting on the function call of factorial(3-1) to complete.
- Fourth call paused, waiting on the function call of factorial(2-1) to complete.
- Fifth call paused, waiting on the function call of factorial(1-1) to complete.

Now 1-1 is 0, so we finally hit our first if block and we return 0. Now we go back to that fifth call. That line "int j = i * factorial(i-1)" can now complete. Here, i is 1. So i * the return result of factorial(1 - 1) which is 1 is j = 1 * 1. So j = 1. We now continue along to the next line and print that. There's your first output result. Then you can return that value 1.

We now go back to our fourth call. Here, i is 2. So the function is int j = i * the result of factorial (1 - 1) which we just returned as 1. So we do j = 2 * 1 which is 2. We print that value, then return it.

Starting to get the pattern? We can then go to the third call, where i was 3, so we're doing 3 * the return result of the previous which is 2. 3*2 is 6. Print and return. And so on until you get all the way back up.

If you can understand all of that, you should be able to go back to your original problem. In your case, there is a little more being passed along with the recursion, but the idea is more or less the same. Once the function gets called the first time, the call will "pause" until you finally hit the case where n == 1. When that happens, the code will jump back to the previous call and so on and so forth similar to the factorial problem. That is when the print statements will be run.

As somebody commented on your original question, if you're still confused, the best way would be to load this code into a program like Eclipse, and step through the code with a debugger. That way you can see the values at each step along the way down the recursion. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To answer you final question, "When are the lines after that executed?"... They are executed after the recursive call has finished executing.

To avoid infinite recursion, there needs to be an exit condition that doesn't continue to recur. In your Towers of Hanoi example, the exit condition is

```
 if(n == 1) {
     System.out.println("Disk 1 from " + from + " to " + to);
 }
```

In your example, the recursive method calls are called with `n - 1`. In other words, after a few recursive calls the number will reach `1`. When it does, the method exits and control is handed back to the caller which executes its next statement until it also terminates and hands back control to its caller and so on.